# Error running *.c file in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: c, eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-kepler

I've started programming in C so weeks ago, and I choose Eclipse Kepler as my IDE for C, since I had already used it for programming in some other languages and really liked.

However, after I had installed *Cygwin* and the C programming tools in Eclipse, I tried to run the old "Hello World" and it didn't work, It didn't appeared anything in the Console, only the message "Terminated".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone has any idea what the problem could be?

---

Thanks to all of you. I tried everything you said but I wasn't able to get my problem solved. I gave up! Right now, i'm using as workspace in eclipse the Cygwin home. I write the program in the Eclipse and run it in the Cygwin command line. 
Again, thanks to all for trying to help, it won't be forgotten. You're a really awesome crowd!

Comment: Try adding a newline to flush stdout: printf("Hello World!\n");

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the program was too fast for you to see it?
The window with the program output appeared and disappeared in the blink of an eye.

You could try to prevent that from happening by changing your program to do its stuff **AND** wait for ENTER before it terminates.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World!");
    getchar(); /* simple wait for ENTER, error prone in more complicated programs */
    return 0;
}
```

Note: your original program "prints a string"; this version "prints a string and waits for ENTER". It's a program with different requirements. If you want to keep to your initial requirements, try running the program from the DOS console.

Comment: @MkWTF And if you run from Eclipse, still nothing?

Comment: See the image I shared in the first comment of this answer. It doesnt appear anything at all!

Comment: By the title in the Console pane it appears you're running "WTF.exe", but, according to the Cygwin windown, your source code was compiled to "hello". Maybe you need to reconfigure your eclipse editor.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to system("pause") may this can help

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World!");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```